# Convert string to datetime in django?

Tags: python, django

i want to display time in 12 hour format in django templates as iam storing time data in a charecter eg('18:30:00') field how to convert this string time data to date in django/python?

Answer (score 3):

If you absolutely must do this, use [`time.strptime`](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strptime). It would be a better idea not to store structured data in a string if you can avoid it, though.

Answer (score 1):

Within Django's templates you can use the `date` Template Filter:

```
{{ value|date:"h:i:s a" }}   # '18:30:00' would appear as  6:30:00 p.m.
{{ value|date:"g:i:s a" }}   # '18:30:00' would appear as 06:30:00 p.m.
```

`value` would be the string variable you pass in the Context to the Template when you render it. The string appearing after `date:` formats the time.

You can find more here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#date

---

Hank Gay's answer is more correct than mine; you should avoid keeping structured data in a string if at all possible.