# convert string to datetime in python

Tags: python, django

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert string to datetime in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5719296/convert-string-to-datetime-in-django)

how to convert time string like '18:30:00' into datetime in python?

Comment: Is the "Django" tag here supposed to indicate that you're using Django (and hence any helper functions in Django are available), or that you specifically want an answer for Django *templates*? If the latter, this is a dupe, otherwise is isn't really, since Python is not the same language as Django templates. One of the answers over there uses a template filter, and the other one is Python but doesn't return a `datetime`, so I see why the questioner might want to ask another, similar question...

Answer (score 2):

Use the datetime.datetime.strptime() method

Answer (score 1):

My post in Daniweb:
[Date string to date object, seconds to readable string](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/code/277460)

You seem to only consider time part, it is trivial to convert by simple split.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strptime

That is the best way to do it